# how start my server process forever through gitlab ci/cd (.gitlab-ci.yml)

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to start my server, but gitlab-runner will kill it after the timeout (1 hour)

my gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
  script:
    - gradle build
    - sudo gradle run &
```

please can help how to run so that he does not kill him

Comment: This is malicious use if the platform. There is no reason for this. Deploy another server

Answer (score 2):

Gitlab terminates the runner, and thereby all subprocesses, after the timeout. There's no way around that.

That is aside from the question why you think you need/want to abuse the ci-runner for perpetually executing something.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it right?
through the service?